# Enable Compass OSMDROID

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid, compass-geolocation

How I can enable the compass mode in Open Street Map?

Is there a method or do I need to create the orientation system by myself?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I enable the compass:

```
MapView oMap;
IMapController mapController;
.......

mapController = oMap.getController();
mapController.setZoom(zoom);
mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude));
MyLocationNewOverlay oMapLocationOverlay = new 
MyLocationNewOverlay(getApplicationContext(),oMap);
oMap.getOverlays().add(oMapLocationOverlay);
oMapLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();
oMapLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();   

CompassOverlay compassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(this, oMap);
compassOverlay.enableCompass();
oMap.getOverlays().add(compassOverlay);
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the compass on the map, use `enableCompass()` in `MyLocationOverlay`.

From [MyLocationOverlay.java](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/MyLocationOverlay.java?spec=svn966&r=966#601):

> Enable orientation sensor (compass) updates and show a compass on the
>   map. You will want to call enableCompass() probably from your
>   Activity's Activity.onResume() method, to enable the features of this
>   overlay. Remember to call the corresponding disableCompass() in your
>   Activity's Activity.onPause() method to turn off updates when in the
>   background.

If you want to rotate the map as well there's a branch of `osmdroid` implementing that functionality: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/branches/rotation/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/MapActivity.java?r=914

Comment: Yes that is useful but I need to rotate the map as well

Comment: Then you should update your question, or ask a new one. As far as i can tell, this is not supported in osmdroid.

Comment: Yes I found the solution : http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/branches/rotation/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/MapActivity.java?r=914

Comment: In trunk, MyLocationOverlay says it is deprecated by MyLocationNewOverlay, but MyLocationNewOverlay does not have an enableCompass() function. Is there a new way to draw the compass?

Comment: Old question and answer, but osmdroid does do map rotation

Answer (score 0):

Since the question isn't clear, I'll give you what I "think" you're asking for, which is a compass on the screen.

```
CompassOverlay mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(getContext(),
            new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(getContext()),
            mMapView);
mCompassOverlay.enableCompass();
mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mCompassOverlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass context and mapview instance

```
CompassOverlay compassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(this, map);
compassOverlay.enableCompass();
map.getOverlays().add(compassOverlay);
```

create compass overlay, enable and then add it to the map overlays to show